# jquery ajax cache false but issues with ie bassed browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, browser-cache

below code works perfect on firefox and chrome however getting strange issues with ie.
I test it myself many times with ie 6,7,8 and 9 seem works to me. the problem facing when clients request the page and function sometimes calls sometimes not.

```
  Close:function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'URL',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        eval( data ) ;
        if ( json_data.status ) {
            CountDown.close();
          }
        else {
            setTimeout(CountDown.Close, 1000);
          }
      },
      error: function() { setTimeout(CountDown.Close, 1000); } 
    });

  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The cache problems with AJAX and IE are too many in this world and you have some things that should help you solve this problem.

You may try many of below:

Add these meta tags in the html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
```

Add these response headers to called url application:

```
Cache-control: no-cache
Expires: Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 00:00:00 GMT
```

If you are developing within IIS, set this key in the application Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <add name="CacheProfile1" duration="60" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
<system.web>
```